# How to calculate return and cum. return in a two dimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate the return as well as cumulative return for a data set of stock returns in a two dimensional array.

So in practice I'm trying to write another sub that declares a two dimensional array with return and cumulative return to do the same job, as the cumulative return function as stated below. The range value may be directly assigned to a two-dimensional array, and vice versa. We don't need to use the .Offset function.

This is the stock returns (data of 20 numbers "the returns"):

```
0
-0,0055
0,0019
0,0144
0,0161
-0,0032
-0,0054
-0,0018
0,0123
0,0072
0,0071
0,0085
0,0207
0,0134
-0,0149
-0,0017
0,0138
-0,0034
-0,0287
-0,0155
-0,0210
```

I've already calculated the cumulative return using the following code:

```
Sub ReadWrite()
    Dim dataRange As String, startRange As String, outRange As String
    Dim i As Integer, nData
    Dim ret, cum_ret

    Worksheets("Stock").Activate
    Columns("C").ClearContents
    dataRange = "B2:B22"
    startRange = "B2"
    outRange = "C2"
    nData = Range(dataRange).Count
    cum_ret = 1

    For i = 1 To nDat
        ret = Range(startRange).Offset(i - 1, 0)
        cum_ret = (1 + ret) * cum_ret
        Range(outRange).Offset(i - 1, 0) = cum_ret
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Are you having problems with your existing code or are you asking someone to write some new code for you?

Comment: I'm asking for help to write a new code, It's a question regarding my homework and I'm stock - I'll type the whole question of the assignment, that may clarify:

Comment: "3. (Read and write data)
“Lecture4_FunctionProcedure.xlsm” module “Example 2” introduces three sub procedures to read returns data from the Excel spreadsheet, calculate the cumulative returns, and write the results in the spreadsheet. In this exercise, you write another sub ReadWrite_Array2() and declare two- dimensional arrays ret and cum_ret to do the same job. Please note that a range value can be directly assigned to a two-dimensional array, and vice versa. So you don’t need to use .Offset to read and write data cell by cell."

Comment: It is best to make an attempt first before asking for help, review this post on asking homework questions...https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions